# use OR operator in google sheet to extract data

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am using the importxml to fetch data in google sheet, sometimes the table data is showing null using, so I have to change the url. Is there any if condition be added in the same cell to use the 1st url (from column A) and if results null then use the url from column B.

cell A2 URL = https://www.screener.in/company/AGI/consolidated/
cell B2 URL = https://www.screener.in/company/AGI/#quarters

using below importxml function in cell C2

IMPORTXML(A2,"/html/body/main/section[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[13]") result #N/A

If the result is #N/A, then use 2nd url from column B2 to get the data
IMPORTXML(B2,"/html/body/main/section[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[13]") result 558

I am not sure how to use the OR operator or any other condition in google sheet

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IFERROR` which is saying if the first result outputs any error, try something else instead.

Here is the formula:

> =IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A2,"/html/body/main/section[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qhQX.png)/td[13]"),IMPORTXML(B2,"/html/body/main/section[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qhQX.png)/td[13]"))

[image: Screenshot]

Or you can try `IF` with `ISNA` like in the formula below, which is basically saying "If the first `IMPORTXML` results in `#N/A`, try a different `IMPORTXML`.  If it does not result in `#N/A`, go ahead and use the first `IMPORTXML`.

Here is that formula.

> =IF(ISNA(IMPORTXML(A2,"/html/body/main/section[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qhQX.png)/td[13]")),IMPORTXML(B2,"/html/body/main/section[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qhQX.png)/td[13]"),IMPORTXML(A2,"/html/body/main/section[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qhQX.png)/td[13]"))

[image: Screenshot2]

In this particular case both results in C2 are the same.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work for you?